# Random number from (0,1) in c

Tags: c, random

I want an exponentially distributed variate, and it seems pretty efficient to do:

```
double exp_variate(double lambda){
    return -log(my_random_function())/lambda;
}
```

where my_random_function gives a double x, so `0 < x < 1` (strictly) meaning that I don't ever get `-log(0)` or `0`. How would I get a random number that excludes the 0 and 1 values. I'm sure someone would have asked this before, but I can't see it. Also, I'm open to other ways of generating exponentially distributed values.

EDIT: > to <

Comment: How about explicitly checking for 0 or 1 and rejecting the random number.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you meant `0 < x < 1`, since a number can't be simultaneously less than 0 and greater than 1.

In that case, I'd probably do something like:

```
double my_random_function() { 
    return (rand() + 1.0) / (RAND_MAX+2.0);
}
```

C's random number generator normally produces numbers from 0 to RAND_MAX. This adds one to the value produced by the random number generator, so it can't produce 0. Dividing by RAND_MAX+1 would give us results from 1/RAND_MAX to (RAND_MAX+1)/(RAND_MAX+1), so the latter is 1. Since we want to avoid that, we use (RAND_MAX+2), so we get 1.0/(RAND_MAX+2) through (RAND_MAX+1)/(RAND_MAX+2), which will be something slightly greater than 0.0 to something just a tad less than 1.0.

Comment: Very reasonable; alternatively on a UNIX system use `drand48` + rejection sampling to throw out zero.

Comment: Except that `1.0/(RAND_MAX+2)` does not exist exactly as a floating point number, so the resulting distribution cannot be uniform. Stephen Canon's solution on the other hand should work.

Comment: @R: I'm not sure what you're after. *Any* conversion to the range (0.0..1.0) necessarily has some non-uniformity. A denominator with any prime factor other than 2 can't be represented precisely. RAND_MAX+2.0 is no easier or harder to deal with than the others though, unless RAND_MAX+2.0 exceeds the range that can be represented precisely. In the typical case (32-bit RNG, 64-bit double) that won't be the case -- a 64-bit double has a 53-bit mantissa, so numbers in the range +/- 2**53-1 are all represented precisely.